# Time series model to analyze hard disk failure

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, arima, econometrics

I wanted to use time series models to analyze the [Backblaze Hard Drive Data](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/hard-drive-test-data.html). Here SMART features are associated with the hard drive failure. In the failure column, 0 represents healthy drive, and 1 means failed drive. There is another column available in the original data set with the model name. Each day in the Backblaze data center, they take a snapshot of each operational hard drive.  The daily snapshot of one drive is one record or row of data. I am interested to see which model of the hard disk will fail first. How can I get this answer from the following data? I was wondering if you could give me some hints. I appreciate your time! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you please let us know what do those variable mean?

Comment: @forecaster SMART is an in-built HDD function, that works by calculating attribute’s values, used to evaluate the performance of HDDs. This is achieved by a series of record counts by sensors and counters. These attributes corresponds to the temperature Celsius (TC), reallocated sector count (RSC), power-on-hours (POH), and the spin-up time (SUT) of hard disk.  If any one of the 6  attributes triggers i.e. exceeds certain threshold values,  the drive is considered a failure. It was not possible yet to determine that what values of the threshold make the hard disk failed!

Comment: Related article "High Danger of Defect: Machine learning model predicts potential disk failures in Google’s DCs" by Chris Mellor https://blocksandfiles.com/2021/05/10/machine-learning-model-predicts-seagate-disk-failures-for-google/

Comment: @Sycorax I am looking for specific ideas to incorporate time stamp. I think classification models what google did without time series doesn't make sense!

Comment: The article describes a "time-series" approach that just summarizes the recent time-varying data (min, max, mean). This doesn't explicitly model the sequential data values, but this does reflect data values over time. I have a hunch that the way Google did it was to summarize the previous $1,2,3,\dots,T$ days, and make predictions for days $T+1, T+2, \dots, T+k$, as a moving window. The reference is also useful because it provides a baseline: if your belief is correct, and modeling the sequential nature of the data is important, then you'll have a higher accuracy than Google reports.

Comment: @Sycorax Could you please explain a little bit about what did you mean by summarize the previous 1,2,3,…,T days?

Comment: Suppose $T=3$ and $k=1$. Summarize the values for days $0,1,2$, and make predictions for $3$. Then summarize values for $1,2,3$ and predict $4$, then summarize $2,3,4$ and predict $5$, etc.

Comment: @Sycorax Could you please refer any text where I can learn sequential time series modelling. I only know univariate time series to forecast l-steps ahead lead time.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine thing to ask as a question.

Comment: @Sycorax I appreciate your help! One more question, here should I consider failure column value as independent variable and timestamp as dependent variable like univariate time series?

Comment: That seems like the kind of thing that you could ask in this question by making an [edit].